# Why won't my line break become inactive with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

I tried using JavaScript to turn off the effect of a `<BR/>` tag when my page loaded, but for some reason, it isn't working.  I feel like I made some sort of error, here's my html:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

var brTag = document.getElementById('newline');
brTag.style.display = 'none';

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

Line 1 <BR id = "newline" />
Line 2

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: At the moment `document.getElementById('newline');` is executed, the element does not exist yet, hence it returns `null`. You should get a JavaScript error (*Cannot read property 'style' of null*). It works fine if you execute it when the element exists: http://jsfiddle.net/Z496x/

Comment: Do you know that in an HTML document, the "/" in "<br/>" is just junk?

Comment: I actually had no idea, I knew that you didn't need to close it with `</BR>`, but I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `newline` before it is declared. Try running the script *after* creating the element (i.e., either later in the file, or inside a function that is called later in the file)

Answer (score 1):

What our esteemed colleagues are saying is to either do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var brTag = document.getElementById('newline');
                brTag.style.display = 'none';
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Line 1 <br id="newline" />
        Line 2
    </body>
</html>
```

or this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Line 1 <br id="newline" />
        Line 2
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var brTag = document.getElementById('newline');
            brTag.style.display = 'none';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

That way `<br id="newline" />` exists in the DOM when your code is executed. As it stands now, you are executing your code prior to `<br id="newline" />` being added to the DOM tree.

Comment: Second solution is fine, but there's no window.onready handler. You want window.onload.

Comment: You're correct (dunno what I was thinking...). Updated answer.